# Stub Module method inside rake task with rspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I am working in a project using RoR and Rspect.

I have a rake task which use a method from another Gem called `When2top::iterate`. This method is iterating during the specified time.

```rb
  task :log_stats, [:entity_name, :duration_limit] => [:environment] do |_, args|
    include When2stop
    entity_name = args[:entity_name]
    duration = args[:duration_limit].to_i
    index_data = (Wh2find::INDEXABLES.find entity_name: entity_name).first
    entity_class = index_data[:entity]
    iterate for: duration.minutes do
      byebug
      stats = entity_class.get_stats
      values = Hash[stats.collect { |item| [item[:index_status], item[:count]] }]
      values.each { |k, val|  NewRelic::Agent.record_metric("Wh2find/#{entity_name}/#{k}", val) }
    end
  end
```

So I want to write a test for the task which is using that method but I wasn't use it really because it implies make the test slower (I'm going to need wait for certain time) and don't know how many times the logic inside the block is going to be executed.

I have my specs for the task, but i'm not being able to stub the Module method.

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

Rails.application.load_tasks

include When2stop

describe :wh2find do
  describe :log_stats do
    it 'should log stats' do
      task = Rake::Task['wh2find:log_stats']
      entity_name = TestEntity.class
      duration = "1"

      stub_const "Wh2find::INDEXABLES", [
        {
          entity_name: 'entity',
          entity: TestEntity,
          fields_to_index: {
            name: {
              weight: 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]

      expect(task).stub_chain(:iterate) do |dur, &block|
        byebug
        expect(dur).to eq(duration.minutes)

        expect(TestEntity).to receive(:get_stats).and_return(
          [
            {
              _id: 0,
              count: 10,
              index_status: 'to_index'
            },
            {
              _id: 1,
              count: 5,
              index_status: 'to_reindex'
            },
            {
              _id: 2,
              count: 1054,
              index_status: 'indexed'
            },
          ]
        )
        new_relic_agent = double('NewRelic::Agent').as_stubbed_const
        expect(new_relic_agent).to receive(:record_metric).with("Wh2find/#{entity_name}/to_index", 10)
        expect(new_relic_agent).to receive(:record_metric).with("Wh2find/#{entity_name}/to_reindex", 5)
        expect(new_relic_agent).to receive(:record_metric).with("Wh2find/#{entity_name}/indexed", 1054)
        block.call()
      end

      task.invoke(entity_name, duration)
    end

  end
end
```

Any idea about how could I stub this method and assert the iterated logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could consider using the Timecop gem which lets you traverse and scale time - but there has to be some alternative to that gem which has built in support for testing.

Comment: What is that gem? It is not in RubyGems. If this is your private gem, then you should add some testing helpers to the gem itself.

Comment: @max thank you, yes I could use Timecop to force the method finish quickly, but my objective isn't test that iterate is working but that is being called, so it's not a real solution.

Comment: As @BroiSatse says When2stop is my gem, it's private, but i could do that public. But I don't understand what could I add to my gem to make it more tests friendly. 
Here is the link to the gem repo: https://github.com/wh-2/when2stop
Here is my project: https://github.com/wh-2/wh2find

Comment: This is going to be very hard to test since you would have to stub the method on the rake task instance. But thats really just the tip of the iceberg here - I would worry about memory usage of running this code for N number of minutes.